# Unable to receive body in a twilio message receive service c#

Tags: c#, twilio, messaging

I am trying to receive msg body using Twilio API and webhook. The webhook service is hit when I send message on the subscribed number but the body of the message is null.

C# code snippet below, the requestBody is always null in this case even though I send "hello"

```
TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
var requestBody = Request.Form["Body"];
            var response = new MessagingResponse();
            if (requestBody == "hello")
            {
                response.Message("Hi!");
            }
            else if (requestBody == "bye")
            {
                response.Message("Goodbye");
            }
 return TwiML(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Evangelist Here....

I took a look at your question and thought it could have 2 possible things going on.

The first is it seems that the line `var requestBody = Request.Form["Body"];` may not be parsing the POST request body correctly. You may want to debug and confirm that the `Request.Form["Body"]` does in fact hold the message body being sent in.

The second thing here would be there isn't a default case in the event the if/else if conditions don't evaluate to true. So I wrote up a sample that we tested out on my 7/30 Twitch stream (www.twitch.tv/cldubya) for you. It is written for ASP.NET Core and uses parameter binding to grab the message body. Take a look below.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromForm] string body)
{
    var requestBody = body;
    var response = new MessagingResponse();
    if (string.Equals(requestBody,"hello",StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        response.Message("Hi!");
    }
    else if (string.Equals(requestBody, "bye", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
         response.Message("Goodbye");
    }
    // adding a default message in the event that the if/else if condition doesn't evaluate to true
   else
   {
         response.Message("Couldn't determine what to respond with");
   }
   return new ContentResult { Content = response.ToString(), ContentType = "application/xml", StatusCode = 200 };
}
```

Take a look and let me know what you think.